# Backup installed RPM packages with tar

Tags: linux, backup, tar, rpm, xargs

I would like to have a back-up of all RPMs installed in the system that have the keyword *kernel*.

So far, this is what I have:

```
RPMS=$(rpm -qa | grep kernel-firmware)

echo "$RPMS" | xargs -I '{}' rpm -ql '{}' | xargs tar cfz "$RPMS".tgz
```

This is for just one package, which works well. When I grep for *kernel*, things do not work as expected.

I wish to have each archive with the original package's name.

**EDIT**

I haven't been clear enough. I'm trying to back-up packages which are already installed. I do not have the RPM src files nor the original packages. I wish to do this to be able to rollback some old machines after kernel updates, or just simply be able to move the *packages* on another machine.

I know this is not the proper way to do it, and once they are *extracted* like this, they are no longer packages, but simple tarballs. However, this should suffice for what I wish to accomplish.

As can been seen from the above commands, I'm using `rpm -qa | grep kernel` to query the RPM DB for all of the packages which have *kernel* in their name. I then wish to use `rpm -ql pacakge-name` to to list all of the files on the system and pass them to `tar` to be able to easily move them to another machine.

Comment: Why you are doing what you are doing ?

Comment: The contents of RPMs are already compressed by default with gzip, so compressing them again with it is not terribly meaningful.

You could unpack all of the RPMs and rebuild them using a strong compression format if you really need to squeeze out some more space and don't mind the extra time compressing and decompressing.

Comment: I have made updates to the original post. I hope it's a bit more clear now what it is I wish to do.

Comment: "things do not work as expected" ... can you explain what is going wrong?

Comment: It will keep overwriting the archive until it reaches the end. What I wish is to have an archive for each installed package. I'm thinking of doing a `while read line` loop which might just work.